# Simple http post call not working with android app

Tags: java, android, servlets, post

I've the following code in an android app:

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
          ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
          HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8888/unidad6_eje1_conectarbd/ejecutaPOST"); 
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", "Value my user entered"));
          postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res);
```

But it fails on its last line:

```
http://127.0.0 1: 8888/unidad6_eje1_conectarbd/ejecutaPOST
```

is likely to be configured properly to receive POST requests as if I put that URL in a web browser it gives the error: Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL.

The code for the servlet is the following:

public class LoginImpl extends HttpServlet {

```
public static String nombre="";

String clave="";

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

          String value1 = request.getParameter("value1");

          System.out.println(value1);
    }
}
```

That I don't think should be an issue.

Can anyone give me any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: " Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL" It seems call is being treated as GET call than POST and you don't have GET method in your servlet.

Comment: First always test a webservice and second did your app has the permission to use internet? Has the device or emulator networkaccess. And last but not least is the server 127.0.0.1 (localhost loopback) realy on your device or emulator? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could not access anything over the ip address 127.0.0.1 as your self, because its the loopback. So your android app on the emulator or test device will never reach your application server on your host mashine over this address.
2. Have you tried it with the ip address of the host, which is running your application server?
3. Is your application server accepting remote connections? On which interface do he listen?
4. Has your android app the permission to use internet and has your test device or the emulator network access to the same network as your application server?

Your code is correct but your setup is screwed up ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, I'm now answering your questions 

I tried to exchange the POST method with the GET method executing it on the GAE URL but it's no use.

My app has the permission to use the Internet is it's able of accesing a sql database on server, it's the interface it seems to be able to listen.


Uh? Network call on the UI thread? Can anyone tell me about that? Sorry for not answering separately but I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that people have said so far is a possibility but nobody has asked if you are running the network call on the UI thread. If you are, your app simply will not work because of potential hangups, you will want to look into AsyncTasks to solve your problems.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, I'm now answering your questions 

I tried to exchange the POST method with the GET method executing it on the GAE URL but it's no use.

My app has the permission to use the Internet is it's able of accesing a sql database on server, it's the interface it seems to be able to listen.


Uh? Network call on the UI thread? Can anyone tell me about that? Sorry for not answering separately but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: So if you want to use HttpPost and such, in order to actually access a webserver you have to start up another thread to do it on. Any access like this is not permitted on the thread that controls the UI because it could cause the app to hang up and crash with an ANR error which is no good. AsyncTasks are commonly used in order to do this so you should check them out.

Comment: I tried to put it apart on an AsyncTask but still the same... Well, thanks a lot for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: Well it's not exactly the same, I entered debug mode and now the post call is being done, but it doesn't seem to work whatever I put in the doPost method.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should update your original post to reflect your current code. The line that NEEDS to be in the AsyncTask is  String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res); because that is the actual network call.